# How to start test container for Pax-Exam?

Tags: osgi, maven-3, pax-exam

I might be asking a trivial question. Just started to learn OSGi with Pax-Exam.

What I did is a mvn archetype:generate for Hello World. I changed the AppTest.java with importing PaxExam related imports and other stuffs. Changed pom.xml accordingly as well to include proper dependencies.

When I do mvn dependency:analyze it says,

[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-native:jar:3.4.0:test

And when I do mvn test, I am getting the following error

Tests in error:
  initializationError(com.test.maven.AppTest): No service org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory found in META-INF/services on classpath

Can anyone please help on how to resolve this? I don't know how to proceed here.

Or Am I trying to make Apple look like an Orange? Meaning, Pax Exam can only work with jar's in src/test/resources/META-INF/services/ ? Like installation in Apache Felix or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THe first thing you should do is create a separate test project often called itests. Pax exam does not work well when you directly integrate it into the project where you have your sources to test.

So create a structure like this:
/mymodule1
...
/mymodulen
/itests

In the mymodule projects you typically create your bunddles with the maven bundle plugin. You should be able to install them into your OSGi framework.

Then in the itests directory you put the pax exam dependencies into the pom file. Also put dependencies to your own modules you need as well as their dependencies.

THen in your pax exam test you define the modules you need in the @Comnfiguration annotated method. I have [created a pax exam example for the apache karaf container here](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2/tree/master/itest/karaf/src/it/regression-karaf/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/exam/regression/karaf).

So you see that in the test I setup the karaf container and add pax-exam-sample8-ds which is the module I want to test.

The [getting started section in the user doc](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Karaf+Container) guides you through the example project:

Unfortunately I did not yet setup such a simple example for the simple felix and equinox containers. So it might be a good idea to start with the karaf example even if you plan to use the plain containers as it might get you started faster.

As soon as I got some free  time I plan to also add such a simple example test project for the plain OSGi container tests.

Comment: As I tried creating the project, I am getting the below exception. Any ideas?

BundleException: The bundle "org.apache.felix.gogo.commands_0.4.0 [332]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.osgi.service.command; version="0.4.0"

I also added the below based on some googling.
<Import-Package>
  org.apache.felix.service.command,
  org.apache.felix.gogo.commands,
  org.apache.karaf.shell.console,
  *
 </Import-Package>

Comment: I think your gogo version might be too old. Can you try with the 0.10 version? http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.felix|org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime|0.10.0|bundle

Comment: Scheider I tried that. Now tests are running successfully. But I am getting the below Exception. Can we ignore it or am I missing something?

14:34:25.091 ERROR [[ACCESS_RUNTIME] NodeCleaupShutdownHook] [Logger.java:252] Executing NodeCleaupShutdownHook.
Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.<init>(ListenerQueue.java:62)

Comment: Judging from the position of this exception in the source it looks like maybe your are just missing the EventAdmin module. As it is optional it should not be an issue.

Comment: is there some simple way to overcome this exception? It's coming just after printing Test result status. So it feels like there is something wrong with the config!

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to just install the felix event admin bundle. http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-event-admin.html

Comment: The link for the example is broken.

Comment: Will look into it

Comment: Link still dead ;)